# mysql error 1064 WHERE

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I need help... trying to set up password for mysql

I started with creating a user: It worked!

```
mysql> CREATE USER admin@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

I am trying to assign a password and that is not working and I am getting the error below:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD <'PHP1234'> WHERE USER = 'admin';
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE USER = 'admin'' at line 1

Can you please help with the error message I am getting or how I need to write it instead?

Comment: `PASSWORD <'PHP...'>` is incorrect, the angle brackets should not be there. Have you tried using [`GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) instead?

Comment: The angle brackets should be parentheses. `PASSWORD` is a function name.

Answer (score 0):

The angle brackets should be parentheses You can set password for users in two bellow syntax:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('new-password-here') WHERE USER='user-name-here' AND Host='host-name-here';
```

**OR**

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'user-name-here'@'hostname-name-here' = PASSWORD('new-password-here');
```